# Rabbitmq Server gets too slow

Tags: rabbitmq

I have some Rabbitmq server issues installed in Centos 7 when starting and stopping it. The server works well when connected to internet. It only takes 1 or 2 seconds to start it. But when disconnected to internet, it takes about 3~5 minutes to either start or stop it. There seems nothing wrong on the access log.

I also checked what to set up in the configuration file. But I couldn't find any settings about starting server. Can you guys give some help for me?

Comment: have you checked logs if it tries to connect somewhere ?

Comment: There is nothing shown on the log while the server is on starting, but only success messages printed on the log when it is just started which takes 3~5 minutes though.